# Salesforce Update a Child's Child when Parent runs a logic

Tags: salesforce, apex

Hi I have the following code where I am taking IDs from a child and then looking the same in parent. Then when my conditions passes, I would want to update my Child's child

My Code:

```
list<Stripe_Customer__c> Clist = new list<Stripe_Customer__c> 
                                                ([Select Id, Distributor__c, FBO_Name__c, FLP_Email__c, Language_Preference__c,
                                                (select Id from Stripe_Invoices__r where Attempt_Count__c = 1 
                                                                AND Paid__c = false
                                                                AND Missed_Payment_Email1__c = FALSE
                                                                AND Invoice_Date__c = TODAY AND Live_Mode__c = TRUE 
                                                                AND Attempted__c = TRUE limit 1) 
                                                                from Stripe_Customer__C
                                                where Id IN (select Stripe_Customer__c from Stripe_Invoice__c 
                                                                where Attempt_Count__c= 1
                                                AND Paid__c = false 
                                                AND Invoice_Date__c = TODAY
                                                AND Live_Mode__c = TRUE 
                                                AND Attempted__c = TRUE
                                                AND Missed_Payment_Email1__c = FALSE)]);

        for(Stripe_Customer__c cid : Clist){
            Dlist.add(cid.Distributor__c);
        }

        List<account> Alist = new List<account>([ SELECT name, Email_FLP_com__c, Language_Preference__c ,
                                                 (select Distributor__c from Stripe_Customers__r where Provision_Status__c='active')
                                                 from account where Distributor_ID__c IN: Dlist]);
```

for(Account c : Clist){

//My code
}

```
c=Stripe_Customer__c;
{
c.Stripe_Invoices__r[0].Missed_Payment_Email1__c = true;
            c.Stripe_Invoices__r[0].Missed_Email1_Date__c = system.today();
            c.Stripe_Invoices__r[0].Email_Response__c = resultBodyGet;
            InUpdate.add(c.Stripe_Invoices__r[0]);
}
update InUpdate;
```

Now would like to update List InUpdate = new List(); which is in Lookup with Account and Child with Stripe_Customer__c

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You are already doing such an update in your code when you are calling 'update InUpdate' in the end of it - just make sure you query all the fields that you need in the 'Clist' and make the changes.

Aside from that what pops up right away is that you can't loop 'Clist' in Account loop as these are different objects. Also as it is written right now it looks like you are doing the update in a for loop which is a bad practice and you should avoid doing it. You should check the developers guide on bulkifying your code.